# Typescript: using returned type of prop method as parameter option for other prop

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have the following react component -

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

export type PickByType<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: T[P]
};

type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc';
type SortableValue = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | Date;

type ValueGetter<D extends object, R extends SortableValue> = (row: D) => R;
type ValueFormatter<V extends SortableValue, D extends object> = (value: V, row: D) => string;
type RenderCell<V extends object, D extends object> = (values: V, row: D) => ReactNode;

type TableColumnWithDataField<D extends object, V extends SortableValue> = {
    label: ReactNode,
    field: keyof PickByType<D, SortableValue>,
    valueGetter?: never,  
    valueFormatter?: ValueFormatter<V, D>, // <--- first parameter should have the same type as selected field in the data. Something like D[field]
    renderCell?: RenderCell<Record<string, SortableValue>, D>, // <--- all values
    sortable?: boolean,
};
type TableColumnCustomField<D extends object, V extends SortableValue> = {
    label: ReactNode,
    field: string,
    valueGetter: ValueGetter<D, V>,
    valueFormatter?: ValueFormatter<V, D>,
    renderCell?: RenderCell<Record<string, SortableValue>, D>, // <--- all values
    sortable?: boolean,
};
type TableColumnWithoutField<D extends object> = {
    label: ReactNode,
    field?: never,
    valueGetter?: never,
    valueFormatter?: never,
    renderCell: RenderCell<Record<string, SortableValue>, D>, // <--- all values
    sortable?: never,
};

type TableColumn<D extends object, V extends SortableValue> = 
  | TableColumnWithDataField<D, V> 
  | TableColumnCustomField<D, V> 
  | TableColumnWithoutField<D>
;

export type TableProps<D extends object, TC extends TableColumn<any, any>> = {
    data: D[], // array of objects, it could be whatever  
    columns: TC[],  
    sortDefaultColumn?: NonNullable<TC["field"]>, // <--- additional question #2
    sortDefaultDirection?: SortDirection,
};

const Table = <D extends object, V extends SortableValue, TC extends TableColumn<D, V>>(props: TableProps<D, TC>): null =>
{
  console.log(props);
  return null;
};
```

`data` contains data for table. This is array of object and it could be whatever.
`columns` describes table columns. Each column could be one of three types (`TableColumnWithDataField`, `TableColumnCustomField` or `TableColumnWithoutField`). Two of them can take `valueGetter` and `valueFormatter` prop methods. And I'd like to use type returned from `valueGetter` as type for the first parameter of `valueFormatter`.
Or detect type of `field` prop which is key if `valueGetter` is optional and has not been specified.

The 1st type - `TableColumnWithDataField` props:

- `label` is just a view label of column. It's the same for each type, don't pay attention on this prop
- `field` is a field key from the data. But we can use only fields which is extended to `SortableValue` type. I filter them with `PickByType` generic.
- `valueFormatter` can be used to converting cell value to string. This is optional prop. Value returned from this function will be used for searching. The typical example again with date fields. `data` could be `{dob: new Date()}`. In `valueFormatter` we can convert it to the human format but without any formatting - `valueFormatter: (value, row) => value.toDateString()`. The first value param should be `Date` type as `data[field]` is `Date`.
- `renderCell` is a method to format cell. It allows JSX.
- `sortable` is a flag indicating if can sort data by this field.

The 2nd type is `TableColumnCustomField`. It could be used for not-existing fields. As example `data: [{firstName: 'fff', lastName: 'lll'}]` but we want to use combination of these fields -
`valueGetter: ({firstName, lastName}) => '${ firstName } ${ lastName }',`. `valueGetter` is required for this type. And the first parameter of `valueFormatter` should have type returned from `valueGetter`.
`field` prop should be a string for this column type. It could be used in `sortDefaultColumn` prop.

The 3rd type is `TableColumnWithoutField`. This is pretty simple type. Can be used to add some additional column. As example column with action buttons or with checkbox for each row. This type can't have `field, valueGetter, valueFormatter and sortable` props. And `renderCell` is required for it.

```
<Table
  data={[
    {id: 1, label: 'label 1', active: false, date: new Date},
    {id: 2, label: 'label 2', active: true},
    {id: 3, label: 'label 3'},
  ]}
  columns={[
    {
      label: 'column 1',
      field: 'date',
      valueFormatter: (value, row) =>
      {
        // "value" is SortableValue but it should be "Date | undefined" as date is optional in the data 
        return '';
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'column 2',
      field: 'custom',
      valueGetter: (row) => row.label + 'custon text',
      valueFormatter: (value, row) =>
      {
        // "value" is SortableValue but it should be "string" as valueGetter returns string
        return '';
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'actions',
      renderCell: (values, row) => <>JSX</>,
    },
  ]}
/>
```

I've tried to do the similar on much smaller and simpler objects and it works, but it's always `SortableValue` here. It seems like TS "doesn't see" the passed parameter to the generic. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

[Live example on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcA5FATIwNwBQnSAHpLDgwAnmHIAFYGgDWAIWEAVUUgA8C7ADUAfHAC8uTnCNwA2uLjAAdnGlJhEanAVwUAZydmAunD4wklkncNOAB+OHMALjhLJAA3JChPKIUvTgouThExOABlaBgAEWAWDGAIa31GNzRGOAAfJjJXGq4s8jzYFAAjABskDRQegFdyfVcYKCsAc3rooZAuhNmuiAg+lGsGyyGentmhgKRqKyQSWYKUPwy2uAHhpABxJBg-KBUCn14-APcILoArJAYbAIT7fQK5fLdPp3EY6fQACjoAHcogUAJR6HQIVrKW6DEYAMWgIEurxUwV8-ghHRg0P6BKQ2A+VJ+cD+gIw8LgCNijKiGmwKLRmN0OnGk0sU1x2WQhygAGEkLsKWDqb8AUCsHAWV91ezNVy9Dy+fdXAKhRBUTrRdjWMQyNc8Qp6Qq1vNLAB1YAwAAWFzphOAypI7zVbI5Ws04ZpUN6DPu3JwhmMPW6yqiyHQMAdTJTRmOIaitnsjkkMnkSjE72wtPpsKQWkw+bgppGTxeCRCURi8Sg2DgLbbSGJUFJnag3fx91H4-Jgp1TbgAHpl3AVABaLc0YrjOBgFBQFAgZ5LVy+iA7M6+lDxIS+8iuY-kG5uOCuZVa047kMWax+8gSEuFAADpIRPP1pjgHpgFsHUTELHoSE8FsWHlJVdinOUyEVZUehUZA0GgUMJWmbANmEJcCiXVd1y3DcXBIEgfTKSxBjgABHEZxlYuAAGIAEYW1cOM+inFY1lQSxm3STJnVdd0QEsBUhnGeggxDMNWQhSNgVuGN3DreMGyTFs00WHpM3tUg82MH8kKiUipWbOzhw7V4BUZdyEhrW4myHRlZzJLtPJnElgreBdqJc4w0JwjCeiw6kEgSgigWIlQnKmcjLEo5kaLXTdtxQJiWPKdiuKQHjyn4oS7JEzp43E1Z1mktIZXIF14zdYYlO9P1LxgDSkK0vUI0NGBTLs8yM3wbNcxigtgyQqdewSRbWy855XlWuJ1oCsKxwi3a+w2uKUrwqz0LwtKiKgEiJjIlxcqogq6OK0qYFYiruK+mrBOE0SkBO-bZLk7Iur6HqPVG8ENU5bVKTG2NGphRluRTBpIaQaG+p9f1gOG0MCk0HRMacBTeuU1SYHU5bidJwcjCxymPX6i8hiG+n3i0TgMj4AR4BubHxDoMBXFh-VdO1BQFQMinusUywVAonLKKm4wgLpNETE8bBaMPI9hHZRxpdcbAfTgIirzgRY4GRG8-D7IwWyIqnzScBVdYHQHYAKI4UB2GBccsKdiEsQgdnMvo1C9gAiRCSDjzw3qKhiSuYv62L2SrqusPiACZfcKAOg6KEos6nWly61ViZIyIjLD3bHjUl8aEejbTDKBhtsFl+XsZD3ztC0BEwDFj2RYn3zZa0dEeyjrFOGTIxG5EvoQJ6CApjHif0S4IwWBgIYoGsbZdi4MG1HpFMtZQXQcBMFscGAEgogE7AZsspgv7gATGHIqUeIURqCDA-NgLWSAexIGRDqS4SAKAbRfm-OABdP7pm-owX+BcAEuCAVAoQUARiIOfq-KIABmdBFkohYIwXAchjASFGE8BQFMbsPSuAfk-OyK87LQQwTQ9hSk-4AJbEtIsjR4GiL4ZtQ6c4EhRF5IyS0yJbRiIMDIowtE47DjjhYbuqMEwjFtpzCw8BzyXiQrbcgccAzkAaAcMgxwYhJxcO4SB+j2RgCzuxKw95ALAXUYfZ4J9rCMA4Oo1hdkmHGF4dNARTAhHWBwRtcRDlEk03oNIvhbltoKJ5CiW0cAUSbzoQAagyWpf8vhsmuUCuFCcijhwqLUTIuJfDtG6M8UZNG9wTHwEthYm2ds45ZT0W+XJE5ikhNPu4LKQTpnH1PkwCJMionGBiUYdpRgv40OzKxVwtTYrJVwrsRRhSsTri0AAKRyAADRUMufy0SYosM4E8oAA)

## Additional question #1

Is it possible to collect types of all values in the row to pass them as first parameter to the `renderCell` method? Key should be value from `field` prop and value is returned value from `valueGetter` or value from `data`. For my example above, it should be

```
{
  date: number | undefined, 
  custom: string,
}
```

## Additional question #2

Is it possible to filter `sortDefaultColumn` values and allow only columns with `sortable: true` value?

Comment: It looks interesting. Could you please provide more information about correlation between `data` property and `column`. Does order matter ? What mean flag `active` ? Please provide explanation to each proeprty

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarianfromUkraine,
Actually `data` is just a key-value array of objects. `active` means nothing, it was just an example. I wanted to show that it could have any type data.
`columns` describes each column of the table. We could use 3 different types of the column. `label` is just a view label of column. It's the same for each type, don't pay attention on this prop.  Next I'll describe each column type and their props.

Comment: 1. `TableColumnWithDataField` - if we want to use existing field from the `data`. `field` is a field key from the `data`. But we can use only fields which is extend to `SortableValue ` type. I filter them with `PickByType` generic. `valueGetter` is an optional for that type and can be used to convert value. As example if field contains ISO date string, we can convert it to Date object inside  `valueGetter`. Value returned from `valueGetter` (or taken from `data`) will be used for sorting.

Comment: `valueFormatter` can be used to converting cell value to string. This is optional prop. Value returned from this function will be used for searching. The typical example again with date fields.  `data` could be `{dob: 'iso string'}. In `valueGetter` we can convert it to Date object for correct sorting - `valueGetter: ({dob}) => new Date(dob)`. Then in `valueFormatter` we can convert it to human format but without any formatting - `valueFormatter: (value, row) => value.toDateString()`. The first `value` param should have type returned from `valueGetter` or from `data[field]`.

Comment: `renderCell` is a method to format cell. It allows JSX.

Comment: The 2nd type is `TableColumnCustomField`. It could be used for not-existing fields. As example `data: [{firstName: 'fff', lastName: 'lll'}]` but we want to use combination of these fields - `valueGetter: ({firstName, lastName}) => `${ firstName } ${ lastName }`. `valueGetter` is required for this type. And the first parameter of `valueFormatter` should have type returned from `valueGetter`. `sortable` is a flag indicating if can sort data by this field. This is also available for the previous type. Forget to describe it

Comment: The 3rd type is `TableColumnWithoutField`. This is pretty simple type. Can be used to add some additional column. As example column with action buttons or with checkbox for each row. This type can't have `field`, `valueGetter` and `valueFormatter` props. And `renderCell` is required for it.  
Thank you for your help. Слава Україні!

Comment: thank you, please add your comments to your question, for the sake of readability. Not everybody reads comments. Героям слава!

Comment: I've edited my initial question. Thanks

Comment: What type of value should be in third column ?

Comment: 3rd column is `TableColumnWithoutField` as it has no `field` or `valueGetter` props